# How can I kick a member from my channel quickly when He/She joined to my channel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-telegram-bot

It doesn't work
cause with MessageHandler a new member can't send messages to my channel when he is not admin ... and I want when he join my channel kick from my channel quickly
So what kind of handlers I should use in my script? Is there anyway to callback a function in python-telegram-bot (def start(bot,update)) without a handler?

```py
from telegram.ext import Updater,CommandHandler,MessageHandler,Filters,Handler
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,format= " %(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s ")
logger = logging.getLogger()

token = Updater('TOKEN')

def kicker(bot,update):
    logger.info("User {} get log".format(update.effective_user['id']))
    if update.message.chat_id != 012345678:
        bot.kick_chat_member(chat_id='@Channel_UserName',user_id=update.message.chat_id)


token.dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.status_update,kicker))

token.start_polling()
token.idle()
```